# Error in mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE['password']))
{
    $checkQuery = "SELECT password, id FROM accounts WHERE username='".$db->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username'])."'";
    $checkResult = mysqli_query($db, $checkQuery);
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($checkResult);
if($check['password'] == $_COOKIE['password'] && mysqli_num_rows($checkQuery)>0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $check['id'];
    }
}



?>
```

It shows this error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   string given...

Comment: may be `$checkResult` inside the function `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: The warning explains all: `mysqli_num_rows($checkResult)` ... http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Calling the wrong variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should change

```
mysqli_num_rows($checkQuery)
```

to

```
mysqli_num_rows($checkResult)
```

Comment: Oh , I'm so stupid .. Thanks a lot! I will choose your answer in 12 minutes..